# Why are classes such as ArrayList and HashMap not synchronized?

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronization, hashmap

I'm updating an old project, and I'm wondering whether I should remove some objects marked as "obsolete" in the IDE. The objects in question are Vector and Hashtable. I've done some research, and it seems that the newer counterparts of these objects - ArrayList and HashMap - are basically the same, just not synchonized.

My question is, why should I make the switch? Aren't I just taking away a bit of security from my application in exchange for a small amount of speed? Seems like it's not a monumental decision either way, but I thought I'd see if it was worth the time before making a decision.

Thanks!

Comment: You might not need synchronization if these objects will not be touched by multithreaded/concurrent code (and therefore you won't have to incur possible performance penalties with `synchronized` blocks). `Vector` and `Hashtable` are not deprecated/obsolete in the Java API, you have a choice between them or their non-synchronized counterparts (they expose the same interfaces, respectively). Similarly, in Java 5 and newer, you have access to `java.util.concurrent`, which has perhaps even better performing containers if you need concurrent access containers.

Comment: You can always wrap it with `Collections.synchronizedList();` if needed, but see Jon's answer first

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Aren't I just taking away a bit of security from my application in exchange for a small amount of speed?

If your sole threading security is relying on the synchronization of `Vector` and `Hashtable`, you're almost certainly in trouble.

Usually, coarser-grained operations need to be synchronized - the "synchronize each small operation on the collections and hope that's good enough" approach is almost never what's required, so why take the small hit of having it at all?

If you're sharing mutable data (such as collections) between threads, you need to consider how to do so carefully - using `Vector` and `Hashtable` can give you a false sense of security.

Comment: AFAIK there is [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) as an alternative for synchronized Map implementation.

Comment: And CopyOnWriteArrayList can be useful if you have a low number of writes.

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` incurs a significant performance penalty, and is often not the best approach towards concurrency.

If you need thread-safe collections, use the ones from `java.util.concurrent`.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html) might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that you are getting the 'security' that you think that you are. I've typically found that I want to do the synchronization myself rather than rely on the built-in stuff (be it Vector/Hashtable, or Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())/Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())).

I tend to prefer to create my own lock monitors and control all the locking myself. If I don't do that I tend to forget to lock for complex, multi-step operations and not notice it. I like how it forces you to think about the locking in your system - otherwise it becomes to easy to 'feel' safe when in fact you aren't. Locking is something that can really mess you up and be a nest of bugs if you don't do it right. It is worth the extra thought to put locking in where it is needed and to understand how your locking is protecting access yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Early classes of the Java API, such as `Vector`, `Hashtable` and `StringBuffer`, were synchronized to make them thread-safe. Unfortunately, synchronization has a big negative impact on performance, even when using these collections from a single thread.

It is better to use their new unsynchronized replacements:

- `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instead of `Vector`
- `Deque` instead of `Stack`
- `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`
- `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`

**Code Example**

```
Vector empList = new Vector();
```

**Solution**

```
ArrayList empList = new ArrayList();
```